# EmberJS/Laravel4 todo app not loading resource 404

Tags: ember.js, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

this is bugging me.
I've downloaded and installed the sample app hxxxs://github.com/javiervd/laravel-ember-todo
and everything seems to work fine when I do artisan serve and work with the site at localhost:8000,
but if I just load the site through the app directory localhost/laravel-ember-todo/public the console log immediately tells me:
hxxp://127.0.0.1/todos not found 404 error
I've researched around but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Thanks for shedding light on this issue.

If any more information is required I will be happy to provide.

UPDATE

I've updated todo.js with:

```
/* global App, Ember */

App.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
   namespace: 'laravel-ember-todo'
}),
text: DS.attr('string'),
isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),

todoDidChange: function () {
    Ember.run.once(this, function () {
        this.get('store').commit();
    });
}.observes('isCompleted', 'text')
});
```

but I'm still getting:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 127.0.0.1/laravel-ember-todo/todos
In firebug it's saying the error is occurring at jquery.min.js (line 5).

Comment: What does your `routes.php` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to point it to the `laravel-ember-todo/public` directory. So add `/public` to your `namespace` (I've not used Ember so I have no idea if that would work). Basically, the document root of your website is `localhost`, not `localhost/laravel-ember-todo/public`, so I'm guessing it's building URIs like `/todos`. The `/` makes it an absolute path and as such it's taken from the document root, which is just `localhost`.

This is why most people tend to use virtual hosts and have, for example, `myapp.dev` point to the location of their application's public directory.